# Why does speed flipping make you go faster than normal flipping in Rocket League?

Tags: rocket-league

I understand how to speedflip, but what makes you go so much faster than just normal flipping?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What makes you go much faster than just normal flipping?

That fact that you're also boosting.

There are multiple things called a "speed flip" but the principle for all of them is the same: boosting makes you go fast, and flipping makes you go fast, so doing both at once makes you go even *faster*.

Unfortunately, if you just do a normal forward-flip while boosting, you'll be facing **backwards** for part of the flip, and thus boosting during that portion would slow you down.

To combat this, **traditional speed flips** have you do a *side-flip* (or diagonal flip) instead of forward flip.  In order for the flip to still push you in the right direction, you jump, rotate your car 45-degrees, and then side-flip.  Since both your flip and your boost are not pointing completely forward during this technique, both are less efficient than normal, making this technique only *slightly* faster than simply boosting.

However, in late 2019 Musty discovered the **modern speed flip** in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aCasHy0Idg). By flipping at a *very* precise angle and then flip-cancelling, the butt of your car will be facing almost perfectly forward the entire time, making it measurably faster than a traditional speed flip.  The specific angle required makes this trick *much* more difficult to pull off, but high level players nowadays are able to do it very consistently.

*(there is also a third one, a wave-dash speed flip, where you boost into a wave-dash. This is the slowest speed flip, but it has the advantage of giving you back control of your car immediately)*

---

Nowadays, when most people talk about the "speed flip" they're talking about the modern, Musty speed-flip.  You can practice the (modern) speed flip using this training pack: `BFAA-45A5-7A56-73CC`. The other speed flips will not reach the ball in time.

Comment: very informative, I've been doing it wrong.  I thought the flip was faster in itself, i didn't know I could boost while doing it.  Of course, i have boost bound to the B button so it's hard to boost while flipping.

Comment: @Millard I also have boost bound to B. Doing both at once took some getting used to _(in fact, I remember saying "No one could do this!" at one point)_, but once it "clicks" it will feel so natural that you'll wonder why you ever had any trouble to begin with.

Comment: good to know, thnx!  =)